# Couldn't install reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

why can't I install react, managed to create a node module file but the file will be automatically deleted.
i used command npx create-react-app my-app
here is the screenshot.

```
Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... node_modules
Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting sanbercode/ from C:\Users\ALI ZAIN\Documents\bds-sanbercode-reactjs-batch-32\Tugas-Harian-Part-2
Done.
```

Comment: what version of node are you using?

Comment: Can you include the entire log? I have no way of telling why your installation was aborted.

Comment: i used  windows 10 64bit , node version 16.14.0 , git version 2.35.1 windows.2, npm 8.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 npm cache clean --force
```

then create react app